# Add two datatable with unique columns

Tags: c#, .net

I have two datatables 
dt1 have Id countryID
dt2 have Url and Id

i want to add these two databales
if i use

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    dt1.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
}
```

getting error like column Url already belongs to another datable
please help me how to add these two tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the properties like `ColumnName` and create new `DataColumns`

You get this error because `DataTable` holds a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) to their columns and every column holds a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.table.aspx) to it's DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a single `DataTable` with three columns (`Id`, `CountryId` and `Url`), just create a primary key on each `Id` column, and simply call `dt1.Merge(dt2)`.

**Example:**

```
var dt1 = new DataTable();
var id1 = dt1.Columns.Add("Id");
dt1.Columns.Add("CountryId");
dt1.PrimaryKey = new []{id1};
dt1.Rows.Add(new []{"1", "Austria"});
dt1.Rows.Add(new []{"2", "Iceland"});

var dt2 = new DataTable();
var id2 = dt2.Columns.Add("Id");
dt2.Columns.Add("Url");
dt2.PrimaryKey = new []{id2};
dt2.Rows.Add(new []{"1", "www.austria.at"});
dt2.Rows.Add(new []{"2", "www.iceland.is"});

dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

`dt1` now looks like:

[image]

Comment: You don't need a foreign key, but a primary key. And yes, you can set it manually as I do in my code example above.